# Worpdress unable to upload featured images to posts and media library

Tags: php, wordpress

In  my wordpress project, I am facing a problem. I am unable to upload featured images for my posts. While uploading images it is showing error as `"Unable to upload image,try again later"`  and there is no console error. After research by deactivating all plugins i came into conclusion that issue was with my custom plugin. When i deactivated that plugin evrything works perfectly. How can i solve the issue.

After again activating that same plugin i got following error

```
The plugin generated 445 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.
```

How can i solve the issue? Am new to wordpress and i dont know how to solve it?

Comment: Are you able to post the `445 characters of unexpected output`  here?  I think if you can see what that output is it will lead you to the issue/solution...  Most likely something is trying to `echo` something at the wrong time/hook in your plugin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074477/the-plugin-generated-x-characters-of-unexpected-output-during-activation-wordpr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074477/the-plugin-generated-x-characters-of-unexpected-output-during-activation-wordpr)

Comment: I didint get what you mean, how can i get that 445 characters

Comment: Can you post your plugin code?  You said you narrowed it to that so we if we can see that code we can help debug the issue.

Comment: Plugin have lots of code, how can i complete

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The plugin generated X characters of unexpected output during activation (WordPress)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074477/the-plugin-generated-x-characters-of-unexpected-output-during-activation-wordpr)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would you implement a secure static login credentials system in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103203/how-would-you-implement-a-secure-static-login-credentials-system-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

The most common causes are:

1. White space before or after the PHP opening or closing tags
2. A file encoded in UTF-8
3. Another issue when something is called at the wrong time, or a call that cannot be resolved without intervention
4. Using the WordPress add_option function. Switching to update_option instead can resolve the problem.
   [For detail click here](https://www.toddlahman.com/the-plugin-generated-x-characters-of-unexpected-output-during-activation/)

Comment: I checked for white space and nothing found. I didnt get your 2nd option,What is that?

Comment: If the files were encoded in UTF-8 (the universal language encoding that is the standard) but the server threw errors. Converted the files to ANSI encoding, and the problem may be fixed. http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/protocols-formats/difference-between-ansi-and-utf-8/

Comment: How can i convert that

Comment: It is editor specific, google for your editor. For notepad++ https://superuser.com/questions/762473/ansi-to-utf-8-in-notepad

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38795347/wordpress-plugin-activited-header-already-send-error?rq=1

Comment: This also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074477/the-plugin-generated-x-characters-of-unexpected-output-during-activation-wordpr